# TypeError: debug() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg' when calling method from different class

Tags: python

Please suggest what I have done wrong, I am new to coding.

**1. first.py file:**

```
import logging
class Log:
    def __init__(self,msg):
        self.msg = msg

    def debug(self,msg):
        FORMAT  = "%(asctime)-15s%(message)s"
        logging.basicConfig(filemode = "w", filename="file.log", format = FORMAT, level=logging.DEBUG)
        logging.debug(self.msg)
```

**2. second.py file**

```
import first
first.Log.debug("I am in debug mode")
```

When I run second.py file than I am getting error as 
Logging.Log.debug("I am in debug mode")

```
TypeError: debug() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but the first issue is that you need to initialize an instance of `Log` with the `msg` argument provided. What you are doing here `first.Log.debug("I am in debug mode")` is calling the `debug` method of `Log` without creating an instance.

In your `debug` method the `msg` argument is required, but it's never used. Instead, the method will simply try to fetch `self.msg` defined at `__init__`.

One way this code would work:

```
1. first.py file

import logging
class Log:
    def __init__(self,msg):
        self.msg = msg

    def debug(self):
        FORMAT  = "%(asctime)-15s%(message)s"
        logging.basicConfig(filemode = "w", filename="file.log", format = FORMAT, level=logging.DEBUG)
        logging.debug(self.msg)

2. second.py file

import first
# Note that Log is initialized with the msg you want, and only then we call debug()
first.Log("I am in debug mode").debug()
```